# How do I handle named route variables passed to a controller?

Tags: plugin-development, routes, controller, hook

I'm writing a plugin that uses the registerSiteRoutes hook to create some new routes, and passes those routes to some controllers. In these routes, I have a few pieces of the URL that I'm capturing as named subpatterns. I'm curious how I handle these named variables in the controller that receives them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote @Brandon from [here](https://plus.google.com/116110705947365375372/posts/awJsEZKn2kn):

> Yep you just need to include a $variables argument in your controller
>   function, typeset to an array:
>
> ```
> public function actionArchive(array $variables = array())
> {
>     $variables['year'] ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Gosh, why not write this in the docs? Craft is a bucket of unobvious solutions...

Comment: @Stalinko haha! That is fair. Craft 3 is much nicer though ;)